# Is it possible to infer generic type from inside string template literal

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-inference

The following piece of code does exactly what I intend to know with one caveat, I would like to avoid having to explicit the generic it needs.

```
type EventGroup = {
  actions: "run" | "save"
  other: "bla"
}

export type EventType<T extends keyof EventGroup> = `${T}/${EventGroup[T]}`

const t: EventType<"actions"> = "actions/run"
```

I would like Typescript to infer that:

```
`actions/run` -> valid
`actions/save` -> valid
`actions/bla` -> NOT valid
`other/bla` -> valid
```

Which is what this code does but with an explicit generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a mapped type you then take a union of the values from:

```typescript
export type EventType = {
    [Key in keyof EventGroup]: `${Key}/${EventGroup[Key]}`
}[keyof EventGroup];
```

Testing the validity of the type:

```typescript
const t1: EventType = "actions/run";  // valid
const t2: EventType = "actions/save"; // valid
const t3: EventType = "actions/bla";  // NOT valid
const t4: EventType = "other/bla";    // valid
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsA4gJwPYFcxQLxQDeAsAFBQVQCGAxsAJYaIDOAXFAERpaIdQA+nZlQQcylKBmAALCGnYcARgBsqY0gF8yZCAA8wGNMCihIsBMgAq4aARLlKAbQDSEEFHqIoAazcYAZuZIqJg4ALrsAAYAJISuIBoA9LHwwejYYC5uYRqRZBqOviABQcjp4QDc2qQ0TMzGwACM7KlWNvictAx1idy8FRSJiVBwVMr0ACZktSwNAEwtFsDWZgQcXYwsicKiA0MjY5PTdQ0AzIvBK7addJvMiSpqA1D7AHIA8pYH41M1JyYAFgubVWnCksjQD1UHGeg2Gox+ZCAA)

There are two parts to that, first the mapped type:

```typescript
type EventType = {
    [Key in keyof EventGroup]: `${Key}/${EventGroup[Key]}`
}
```

which evaluates as:

```typescript
type EventType = {
    actions: "actions/run" | "actions/save";
    other: "other/bla";
}
```

Then we use `[keyof EventGroup]` on the end to extract just the values of `actions` and `other` as a union.

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a bunch, Typescript keeps surprising me with its versatility and power but underwhelming me with it's docs and resources. I googled like a mad man, but it's hard to get to the concept you specifically want/need.

Comment: @Trufa - I've had *exactly* that reaction. But the docs are improving, so we'll keep a good thought. Happy coding!